# How can I remove desktop environments on 18.04

Tags: desktop-environments

I have a home server running Ubuntu Server 18.04. 
I came across a couple of tasks that I needed a GUI for so I installed xfce4. I didn't get on with this so I quickly uninstalled it using:

```
sudo apt remove --purge xfce4
sudo apt autoremove
```

I thought this had removed it. After a complete error using 'tasksel' I accidentally removed everything somehow. Long story short I installed Ubuntu desktop. I found this a little graphically intensive so I installed Mate.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Now when I run

```
ls -l /usr/share/xsessions
```

I am returned

```
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7001 Feb 13  2018 mate.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  323 May  2  2018 ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  247 May  2  2018 ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5465 Sep 22  2016 xfce.desktop
```

So I can see mate here which is fine but I thought I uninstalled xfce. Also how do I go about removing ubuntu.desktop? I am not even sure what the other option is here. 
I have searched but I only seem to find information for 12.04 or older which doesn't appear to work. 
Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to proceed like this:

- see the packages contained in the ubuntu-desktop task:

// root account

```
# apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop
```

The commands show two sections : Depends and Recommends.

To discard the superfluous text we can give the following commands:

```
# apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep Depends: | sed 's/, / /g' - | sed 's/Depends://g' -
```

AND

`# apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep Recommends: | sed 's/, / /g' - | sed 's/Recommends://g'` -

Commands seem to return decent output, to be used with apt-get, to remove auto-installed packages from tasksel ubuntu-desktop

We give the following compound command to proceed with the uninstallation of the packages:

```
# apt-get purge $(apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep Depends: | sed 's/, / /g' - | sed 's/Depends://g' - )
```

AND

```
# apt-get purge $(apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep Recommends: | sed 's/, / /g' - | sed 's/Recommends://g' - )
```

We proceed to remove all packages dependent on gnome, gtk, kde, ubuntu, and desktop. Now let's see the command that does the job:

```
# apt-get purge $( dpkg   --get-selections | grep gnome | awk {'print $1'} | xargs )
```

To eliminate the other dependencies we replace from time to time the entries gnome, gtk, kde, ubuntu, and desktop, for the matcher -> grep:

```
# apt-get purge $( dpkg   --get-selections | grep gtk | awk {'print $1'} | xargs )

# apt-get purge $(dpkg   --get-selections | grep kde | awk {'print $1'} | xargs)

# apt-get purge $(dpkg   --get-selections | grep desktop | awk {'print $1'} | xargs)
```

For the ubuntu key, the system informs us that if we also delete the ubuntu-keyring package, we will damage it, then we proceed with the removal of the dependencies by discarding the latter package:

```
# apt-get purge $(dpkg   --get-selections | grep ubuntu | grep -v ubuntu-keyring | awk {'print $1'} | xargs )
```

To finish we can give the following command to check if there are any substantial dependencies:

```
# apt-get autoremove --purge
```

To finish we can now install our favorite desktop manager, perhaps with the command:

```
# apt-cache search mate-desktop

# apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

I hope the instructions are of help to some, good debianized ....

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
apt remove --purge ubuntu-desktop
```

To remove the old desktop that are interfering with
each other:

When you're in the folder `/usr/share/session`
do:

```
rm -rf ubuntu-c* ubuntu.d* xfce*
```

Only mate.desktop will be left alone

```
ls -al /usr/share/session
```

Now you just have to reboot and it will be fine.
Tested a few minutes ago on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage, removing it won't remove the other DEs.  And could cause other unintentional removals which could damage the system, so I do not recommend this method.